# Аналоги ssms под linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sql-server

Какие существуют инструменты для работы с СУБД (в частности MS SQL Server) под Ubuntu 17.10 наподобие SQL Server Management Studio или Oracle SQL Developer?

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую HeidiSQL. 
Почти нормально запускается под Wine.